# What is the probability that a triangle is isoceles?

Tags: geometry

I was just thinking about this question and I was wondering whether it would be $0$. Would this make the probability of having an obtuse triangle infinity? This may be really basic, but I really want to know the answer.

Comment: It depends on given information. Are the sides already known? Or are the sides chosen according to some set of rules? (Think triangle inequality). But given that a triangle exists, the probability that a particular side has some value when "everything" is possible (rational and irrational) would technically be zero.

Comment: You appear to think that "isosceles" and "obtuse" are somehow opposite, which they obviously are not.  Perhaps you meant to say "acute"?

Comment: As it stands, there really isn;t a question here.  Under any likely notions, the probability that a triangle is isosceles is $0$ as small perturbations of such a triangle are non-isosceles (while perturbations of scalene triangles are still scalene).  As I said, maybe you meant "acute" but who knows?  Please clarify the question.  If you can not, then I think it should be closed.

Comment: Lulu.  Don't you mean "scalene"?  Scalene means all three sides have different lengths.  Acute means all angles are acute (which can be isoceles, equilateral or scalene) and obtuse means one angle is obtuse (which can be isoceles or scalene, but nt equilateral. )

Comment: The "opposite" of probability is 1, not infinity.  and the opposite of isoceles is scalene.  But yes, the prob of isoceles is 0, and of scalene is 1-0=1.  Prob 0 does not mean impossible and prob 1 does not mean inevitable.

Comment: I'm not seeing how isoceles implies or  refutes acute or obtuse.  I'm afraid I don't understand lulu's comment although s\he certainly has something in mind.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to state a probability question properly it is important to be clear about the universe from which you selecting your special set.

For example, you could ask: Select any three non-colinear points at random in a 1 by 1 square, what is the probability that the triangle they form is isosoceles? There are other ways of asking the question which may or may not be equivalent. In almost all cases I suspect that the answer would be, as you surmised, $0$.

However, the probability they form a non-isosoceles triangle would not be infinity it would be $1$. This is a simple result of elementary probability theory.

Answer (score 1):

here a discussion by Prof. Gilbert Strang on acute and obtuse triangle

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIBxLFXSCKY

following his way of reasoning the probability for isosceles triangle would be zero